# Need of checksum in serial communication

Tags: c#, c, communication, serial-communication

I am currently working on a project involving a Serial COM from PC  ( USB TO SERIAL application coded in C# ) to an embedded platform (STM32F4).
I saw that in some cases it's mandatory to have a checksum in a communication frame. 
The Communication configuration:

**Baud-rate = 115200,**

**No Parity bit,**

**One StopBit,**

**No Handshake,**

**Frame Length : 16 bytes**

Is it worth adding a checksum in my application? What are the reasons why i should (not) have this checksum?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Using a checksum allows you to detect an erronous transmission.

Comment: I understood the principle, but is it really useful for this kind of serial transmission?

Comment: @AlexandreM.  Yes, it is necessary.  Suppose you want to make your application strong enough to detect that you have unplugged the cable or to be able to resyncronize itself to get the framing ok when you replug it.  You can cope with electric noise with this approach.  Have a  look to a book in correcting communication errors to see more.

Comment: On my embedded side unplugged cable cause my system to stop (electronically done) and restart when replugged , and on the Windows side it throw an exception which i catch. I understand that it would be wise to have a CRC to correct eventual errors. I will read more about this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you must have a checksum. The only acceptable non-hobbyist solution is a proper checksum based on CRC. Most common industry standard is "CRC-16-CCITT" (polynomal 0x1021). This will catch any single-bit error, most double-bit errors and some burst errors.

Even though you'll only use RS-232 in an office environment(?), any EMI caused by crappy consumer electronics could cause glitches and incorrect data. There is a lot of such crappy electronics around: for example it is not all that uncommon for the electronics in your PC to have poor EMC performance. In particular, there are countless of USB-to-serial adapters with downright awful quality.

The UART hardware in itself has no error detection worth mentioning: it is ancient 1960s technology. On the hardware level, it only checks data integrity based on start and stop bits, and will miss out any errors in between. (Parity checking is equally poor).

Alternatively, you could perhaps get an USB to RS-485 adapter instead and use RS-485, which is far more rugged as it has differential signals. But that requires that you have RS-485 transceivers on the target side too.

Comment: In my case the RS-232 line is not even 4 cm  long  (On a PCB in between two ground planes), so regarding the EMC perfomance i am think this is okay, isn't it ?. The rest is the USB (differential) with a shielded cable. Do you think it would be an issue?

Comment: @AlexandreM. Ok it wasn't clear how the connection from the PC to the PCB was made, I assumed a standard d-sub "serial cable" with RS-232. USB is indeed more rugged than RS-232. The question is how picky you are with data integrity. Is it fine if it only works 99 times out of 100, or are errors unacceptable?

Comment: @Lundin, Even for hobbists, a proper CRC is better than nothing.  There are plenty of libraries in open source or public domain to do it for you.

Comment: @LuisColorado I was rather giving some would-be professionals a subtle elbow nudge about their products being of lower quality than those of hobbyist enthusiasts. You'd be surprised of all the scary junk implementations that's out there... even in the domain of safety-critical applications.

Answer (score 2):

It is customary to have a checksum in order to verify the correctness of the data although serial communication is relatively reliable. You will definitely need a sync made up of at least two bytes that will always be assigned a specific value which you don't expect to appear in your data. The sync is used in the receiving side to find the start of each message sent because it is a stream communication and not a packet based communication.

Comment: Thank you, why two bytes? I only use one byte to synchronize, would it be enough?

Comment: @AlexandreM. Synchronizing is not really error handling, apart from the fact that any noise in the sync byte itself will cause the following package to be discarded/not found.

Comment: @AlexandreM. As Lundin comments, synchronizing is not error handling, it is simply a method to find out where an application "message" starts. The reason for using two bytes or more, is that using one byte is more prone to be thrown off by an actual data value, causing the receiving side to read the stream incorrectly (thinking the message starts where a data value was equal to the agreed upon sync value)

Comment: I agree on what you said but the combination of two byte could also happen no? The issue here is that i don't want to OVERLOAD the communication frame allowing me to have better performance.

Comment: @AlexandreM. Any combination can possibly happen, having more than one byte reduces the likelihood of this happening that's all. Not having a sync byte at all requires that you know for certain on the receiving side that you get the entire data of one transmission (and only one transmission) in your receive buffer.

Comment: @AlexandreM.  Two bytes allow you to use transparency to allow all possible bytes to be used in data.  Normally two byte sequences are selected for framming or some escape sequences allow you to have an alphabet of more than 256 possible symbols and to be able to allow all 256 characters to be included in your data payload.  If you have read my other comments, a good book in data comunications is a must to enter this discipline.

Comment: @luiscolorado could you please suggest one of such books?

Comment: @AlexandreM.  A classical book in data communications that covers the use of transparency is Tannenbaum's "Computer Networks".  Probably you'll find it obsolete someway, but it's actualised regularly and has the best explanations for the subject you ask for that I've read.  Probably a good option, even having more good books nowadays.