# LED ring in Arduino - How to make an interface in Processing IDE to select a color

Tags: arduino, processing, led

I have 2 different LED Rings. (one has 16 LEDs and the other 24)
I want to make an interface from processing IDE where I can select a color and send this color to the selected ring. Here is the arduino code:

```
#include <FastLED.h>
#define LED_PIN1 3
#define LED_PIN2 12           
#define NUM_LEDS1 16       
#define NUM_LEDS2 24

CRGB leds1[NUM_LEDS1];      
CRGB leds2[NUM_LEDS2];  

     int r,g,b;

boolean state = false;


void setup() {


FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, LED_PIN1, GRB>(leds1, NUM_LEDS1);
FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, LED_PIN2, GRB>(leds2, NUM_LEDS2);

Serial.begin(9600);


}


void loop() {

  String returnedInput = rgbInput();

  String red = returnedInput.substring(0,3); //get 3 values like 255
  String green = returnedInput.substring(4,7);
  String blue = returnedInput.substring(8,11);
  

  Serial.println(red);
  Serial.println(green);
  Serial.println(blue);

  int r = red.toInt();
  int g = green.toInt();
  int b = blue.toInt();

 if (Serial.available()){

      char val = Serial.read();

      if(val == '2') { //selects the second LED ring
        if(state == false) {
          state = true;

          for(int i = 0 ; i < 24 ; i++ ){
            leds2[i] = CRGB(r, g, b); //turn on all the LEDs on the ring to the selected color
            FastLED.show(); 
            FastLED.clear();
            FastLED.show();
            
          }}}
}}

  
  String rgbInput() {

    //prompt for input
    Serial.println("ready");

    while(!Serial.available()) {
      //if 0, it keeps waiting for the user to enter sth.
    }

  String userInput = Serial.readStringUntil("\n");

  return userInput;
}
```

I wrote this for the second LED, if I can manage this one, I will do the same for the other one but it's not working.

And here is the Processing codes:

```
import controlP5.*; //import ControlP5 library
import processing.serial.*;

Serial port;

ControlP5 cp5; //create ControlP5 object
PFont font;
PFont font2;

color col;
Serial serialMonitor;
String prompt;

ColorPicker cp;

void setup(){ //Same as setup in arduino
  
  size(900, 900);                          //Window size, (width, height)
  port = new Serial(this, "COM4", 9600);   //Change this to your port
  
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  
  font = createFont ("Georgia Bold", 20);
  font2 = createFont ("Georgia Bold",15);
  
cp = cp5.addColorPicker("PICKER")
        .setPosition(500,100)
        .setColorValue(color(255,128,0,128))
        ;
       
  
Group configGroup = cp5.addGroup("CONFIGURATION")
    .setPosition(90,100)
    .setWidth(150)
    .setHeight(30)
    .setFont(font2)
    .setBackgroundColor(color(0,0))
  ;
  
  cp5.addButton("PICK_ALL")  // The button
    .setPosition(10, 10)     // x and y relative to the group
    .setSize(160, 150)       // (width, height)
    .setFont(font)
    .setGroup(configGroup)   // add it to the group
  ;     
  
  
  cp5.addButton("PICK_ONE")  // The button
    .setPosition(10, 200)    // x and y relative to the group
    .setSize(160, 150)       // (width, height)
    .setFont(font) 
    .setGroup(configGroup)   // add it to the group
  ;   
  
}


void draw(){  //Same as loop in arduino

  background(150, 0 , 150); //Background colour of window (r, g, b) or (0 to 255)
    
}

public void controlEvent(ControlEvent c){
  
  if(c.isFrom(cp)){
    int r = int(c.getArrayValue(0));
    int g = int(c.getArrayValue(1));
    int b = int(c.getArrayValue(2));
    int a = int(c.getArrayValue(3));
    col = color(r,g,b,a);
  }
}

void keyPressed(){
  
  while(serialMonitor.available() > 0)
  {
    prompt = serialMonitor.readStringUntil (10);
  }
  
  
  println(keyCode);
  
  String sendColor = nf(int(red(col)),3) + "," + nf(int(green(col)),3) + "," + nf(int(blue(col)),3);
  
  println(sendColor);
  serialMonitor.write(sendColor);
  
}

void PICKER(){
  port.write('2');
}

void PICK_ALL(){
  
  port.write('t');
  
}

void PICK_ONE(){
  
  port.write('l');
  
}
```

I don't exactly know how to get the RGB values and use them in CRGB function. It is much easier when using a single RGB LED that uses 3 pins. But I couldn't implement it to an LED Ring that uses only 1 pin.

[image: Here is the processing interface for color picking. I can select the colors but nothing is changing in the LED Ring]

Here is the processing interface for color picking. I can select the colors but nothing is changing in the LED Ring on Arduino.

Comment: You'll be more likely to get an answer if you can do some debugging and narrow this down to the part of your setup that's not working. Does the Arduino work on its own? Can you send a simple string from a stripped-down Processing sketch? Can you send a color value to the Arduino without your Processing UI, etc. It might even lead you to finding the answer on your own.

Comment: The only problem is, that I can't make the color section 'user dependant'. I can send a preselected color value to the Arduino, like CRGB(255,0,0) and it's red. But I want to make it selectable by the user. All the examples on the Internet are for an RGB LED, that has a 3 pin connection. So they're taking the color value from each pin, and write them one by one without an external function. But in this case, since there is one pin, there is a function I should use called CRGB, and I couldn't implement the solutions to this function.

Comment: UI is the second part of it, if I can manage the color selection in Arduino, then I can handle the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reliable serial communication is not trivial. Ideally you would make you own binary communication protocol setting up a packet of bytes with a header that describes how many following bytes actually have data and perhaps even a [checksum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29385417/need-of-checksum-in-serial-communication).

Strings will do to get started and it's great you're using `nf()` to make data easier to parse.

One potential gotcha could be the switch between putting a string together (`rgbInput()`) and reading one char at a time (`char val = Serial.read();`).

I would recommend breaking the problem down into smaller simpler parts, testing/debugging each part, then putting the parts back together one at a time to avoid integration bugs.

For example, the main challenge seems to be serial communication so I'd write a Processing and Arduino sketch to ensure that works reliably before adding in LED control.

Let's go for the option of \n terminated strings, even though it's sending a redundant extra character(e.g. `port.write("2\n");`) it would make buffering simpler:

- always buffer until a newline
- `trim()` the string for newline
- if the trimmed string has length 1 it's a command (like '2', 'l', 't'), otherwise it's a colour triplet

Here's a basic Arduino sketch that uses the ideas above (and a bit of your code ;) ):

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // check if there are at least two characters to receive
  if(Serial.available() > 1){
    // buffer the full string until a new line character
    String returnedInput = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    // remove white space (new line char)
    returnedInput.trim();
    // if it's a single command 
    if(returnedInput.length() == 1){
      char state = returnedInput.charAt(0);
      
      switch(state){
        
        case '2':
          Serial.println("parsed 2 command");
        break;

        case 't':
          Serial.println("parsed t command");
        break;

        case 'l':
          Serial.println("parsed l command");
        break;
        
        default:
          Serial.print("unknown state:");
          Serial.println(state);
        break;
      }
      
    }
    // if it's a RGB triplet
    else if(returnedInput.length() == 11){
      String redString   = returnedInput.substring(0, 3); //get 3 values like 255
      String greenString = returnedInput.substring(4, 7);
      String blueString  = returnedInput.substring(8, 11);

      int r = redString.toInt();
      int g = greenString.toInt();
      int b = blueString.toInt();

      // constrain values to bytes
      r = constrain(r, 0, 255);
      g = constrain(g, 0, 255);
      b = constrain(b, 0, 255);
      // do something with the values (e.g. store globally, etc.)
      Serial.print("parsed RGB: #");
      Serial.print(r, HEX);
      Serial.print(g, HEX);
      Serial.print(b, HEX);
      Serial.println();
    }
    // otherwise error message ?
    else{
      Serial.print("Uknown command: ");
      Serial.println(returnedInput);  
    }
  }
}
```

This should handle string messages with a new line terminator and based on the trimmed length parse either a single char command a 11 char RRR,GGG,BBB string.

You can test directly with Arduino's Serial Monitor.

In your Processing sketch it's unclear why there are two Serial ports (`port` and `serialMonitor`).

Here's a slightly modified version of your Processing sketch that sends either a couple of single char commands or the colour string:

```
import controlP5.*; //import ControlP5 library
import processing.serial.*;


PFont font;
PFont font2;

// Arduino serial port
Serial port;
// colour picker values to send to Arduino
int r;
int g;
int b;

// GUI variables
ControlP5 cp5; //create ControlP5 object
ColorPicker cp;


void setup() { //Same as setup in arduino

  size(900, 900);                          //Window size, (width, height)
  try {
    port = new Serial(this, "/dev/tty.usbserial-A104WS3R", 9600);   //Change this to your port
    // buffer until new line: this plugs in nicely with serialEvent()
    port.bufferUntil('\n');
  }catch(Exception e) {
    println("error opening serial");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);

  font = createFont ("Georgia Bold", 20);
  font2 = createFont ("Georgia Bold", 15);

  cp = cp5.addColorPicker("PICKER")
    .setPosition(500, 100)
    .setColorValue(color(255, 128, 0, 128))
    ;

  Group configGroup = cp5.addGroup("CONFIGURATION")
    .setPosition(90, 100)
    .setWidth(150)
    .setHeight(30)
    .setFont(font2)
    .setBackgroundColor(color(0, 0))
    ;

  cp5.addButton("PICK_ALL")  // The button
    .setPosition(10, 10)     // x and y relative to the group
    .setSize(160, 150)       // (width, height)
    .setFont(font)
    .setGroup(configGroup)   // add it to the group
    ;     


  cp5.addButton("PICK_ONE")  // The button
    .setPosition(10, 200)    // x and y relative to the group
    .setSize(160, 150)       // (width, height)
    .setFont(font) 
    .setGroup(configGroup)   // add it to the group
    ;
}


void draw() {  //Same as loop in arduino

  background(150, 0, 150); //Background colour of window (r, g, b) or (0 to 255)
}

public void controlEvent(ControlEvent c) {

  if (c.isFrom(cp)) {
    r = int(c.getArrayValue(0));
    g = int(c.getArrayValue(1));
    b = int(c.getArrayValue(2));
  }
}

void keyPressed() {

  if(port == null){
    println("no serial, ignoring");
    return;
  }

  String sendColor = nf(r, 3) + "," + nf(g, 3) + "," + nf(b, 3) + '\n';
  println("sending to Arduino:", sendColor);
  
  port.write(sendColor);
}

void PICKER() {
  println("PICKER");
  if (port != null) port.write("2\n");
}

void PICK_ALL() {
  println("PICK_ALL");
  if (port != null) port.write("t\n");
}

void PICK_ONE() {
  println("PICK_ONE");
  if (port != null) port.write("l\n");
}

void serialEvent(Serial s){
  println("from Arduino:", s.readString());
}
```

Overall notice bits of error checking: always a good idea when working with Serial :)

Once this works as expected you can combine the `FastLED` control.

Here's a suggestion:

```
#include <FastLED.h>
#define LED_PIN1 3
#define LED_PIN2 12           
#define NUM_LEDS1 16       
#define NUM_LEDS2 24

CRGB leds1[NUM_LEDS1];      
CRGB leds2[NUM_LEDS2];  

// ring 1 color
int r1,g1,b1;
// ring 2 color
int r2,g2,b2;
// toggle wether to update r1,g1,b1 or r2,g2,b2 when a new colour arrives
boolean updateRing1 = true;

void setup() {
  // setup serial
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // setup LEDs
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, LED_PIN1, GRB>(leds1, NUM_LEDS1);
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, LED_PIN2, GRB>(leds2, NUM_LEDS2);
}

void loop() {
  handleSerial();
  driveLEDRings();
}

void handleSerial(){
  // check if there are at least two characters to receive
  if(Serial.available() > 1){
    // buffer the full string until a new line character
    String returnedInput = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    // remove white space (new line char)
    returnedInput.trim();
    // if it's a single command 
    if(returnedInput.length() == 1){
      char state = returnedInput.charAt(0);
      
      switch(state){
        
        case '2':
          Serial.println(F("parsed 2 command"));
        break;

        case 't':
          Serial.println(F("parsed t command: switching to ring #1"));
          updateRing1 = true;
        break;

        case 'l':
          Serial.println(F("parsed l command: switching to ring #2"));
          updateRing1 = false;
        break;
        
        default:
          Serial.print(F("unknown state:"));
          Serial.println(state);
        break;
      }
      
    }
    // if it's a RGB triplet
    else if(returnedInput.length() == 11){
      String redString   = returnedInput.substring(0, 3); //get 3 values like 255
      String greenString = returnedInput.substring(4, 7);
      String blueString  = returnedInput.substring(8, 11);

      int r = redString.toInt();
      int g = greenString.toInt();
      int b = blueString.toInt();

      // constrain values to bytes
      r = constrain(r, 0, 255);
      g = constrain(g, 0, 255);
      b = constrain(b, 0, 255);
      // do something with the values (e.g. store globally, etc.)
      Serial.print(F("parsed RGB: #"));
      Serial.print(r, HEX);
      Serial.print(g, HEX);
      Serial.print(b, HEX);
      Serial.println();

      // handle ring colour update
      if(updateRing1){
        r1 = r;
        g1 = g;
        b1 = b;  
      }else{
        r2 = r;
        g2 = g;
        b2 = b;
      }
    }
    // otherwise error message ?
    else{
      Serial.print("Uknown command: ");
      Serial.println(returnedInput);  
    }
  }  
}

void driveLEDRings(){
  //update ring 1
  for(int i = 0 ; i < NUM_LEDS1; i++){
    leds1[i] = CRGB(r1, g1, b1);
  }
  //update ring 2
  for(int i = 0 ; i < NUM_LEDS2; i++){
    leds2[i] = CRGB(r2, g2, b2);
  }
  // display
  FastLED.show();
}
```

**Note:** the above code isn't tested with wired RGB LEDs so it might not work but hopefully it illustrates the idea. (You should double check the baud rate, pins, RGB colour channels, etc.)

If the above works as expected using Serial Monitor you can get back to testing the Processing interface sketch.

Additionally bare in mind 9600 is quite a low baud rate.
You should test with higher baud rates (e.g. 115200, 57600) and if it's stable use those to avoid delays driving LEDs while buffering serial data.
In general avoid / minimise blocking (while) loops where you can.

Overall, the idea is to delete/remove anything you don't need in your code to drill down to the problem: work it out in isolation. Once that's debugged and working reliably add new code one bit a time, testing after each addition (otherwise you risk introducing more bugs instead of one which is harder to spot / fix).